# Jmeter select a random value from previous thread group variables

Tags: testing, jmeter

In my test plan, I have a setup thread group. I save the result of that setup thread group as a variable and use it in my following thread group. I was able to achieve this with the JSON extractor.

What I want to do is run the setup thread group multiple times so it can produce a pool of that variable. And in the following thread group, I randomly pick one from the pool to use. How can I achieve that?

I also have a teardown thread group, that needs to read from the pool of variable and tear down one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor in the setUp Thread Group
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   props.put('id_' + vars.get('__jm__setUp Thread Group__idx'), vars.get('id'))
   ```

   this will create the following JMeter Properties:

   ```
   id_0=value from 1st iteration
   id_1=value from 2nd iteration
   etc.
   ```
3. Then in main or tearDown Thread Group you will be able to get the random value using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__P(id_${__Random(0,4,)},)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: For teardown it shouldn't be random, I just changed it to ${__P(id${__jm__tear down thread groups__idx},)}

Comment: Thank you for the help!